# Javascript confirm box with yes or no button

Tags: javascript

I have to save record depend on the user response  either `yes` or `no` , in java script i need confirm box with `yes` and `no`  button. If i press save button all records should be Save, other wise focus on particular control like `textbox`.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> 
       <p id="demo"></p>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          function myFunction(){
             var x;
             var r=confirm("Press a button!");
             if (r==true){
                 x="You pressed OK!";
             }
             else{
                 x="You pressed Cancel!";
             }
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
         }
      </script>
```

instead of yes or no you can use the default values like ok or cancel.

Comment: thank mani, But,if i press cancel or no the record should not be saved , but this code save the record  when i press no button